MySQL select * from table BUT substitute column names with "column description" defined in another table - possible?
I have two tables
table_data



id
col1
col2
col3




1
d11
d12
d13


2
d21
d22
d23


3
d31
d32
d33



table_col_desc



id
col_name
description




1
col1
rain


2
col2
sun


3
col3
wind



What I want to achieve is a view/select with result like:



id
rain
sun
wind




1
d11
d12
d13


2
d21
d22
d23


3
d31
d32
d33



How to achieve this without manually alias it one-by-one?
Thanks a lot.

You cannot set output rowset metadata (columns names) in SELECT statement. You must use dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement) for that. From the other side this is not relational operation, and I recommend you to format the output on the client side.

Thanks! I'll look at dynamic SQL.

You can't do this in one statement. The columns of an SQL statement must be fixed before it begins reading data, so you can't make a query that reads data to determine the names of columns.
You could do it in two statements. One to read the column name mapping, then format the second statement using the results of the first statement.
